# Blackberry 6 Anchor document.location not working

Tags: javascript, html, blackberry

On the Torch 9800 OS 6, my JS call doesn't seem to be working properly.  I've tried multiple approaches:

- Using body onload=document.location+=#page2
- Using a setTimeout() to wait for the DOM to load.
- Placing the JS call at the bottom, which is what I currently have:

The alert pops up, but I don't see any HTML loaded.  * This works on OS 5 *

```
<html>
  <body>
  <a id='page0'/>
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
  <a id='page1'/>
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
  <a id='page2'/>
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onload=function()
    {
       alert('asdf');
       document.location='app:#page2';
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by appending the anchor page to the end of the 'name' where the BrowserField object opens the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
document.location='app://#page2';
```

??

Then maybe puting it in the body tag

```
<body onLoad="document.location='app:#page2';">
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either.  If it helps, I created an onclick event that actually works: `<a onclick=\"document.location='app:#page2'\">page2</a>`  It's weird that this same JS code does not work for onload, that's why I was lead to believe the DOM hasn't been loaded.

Comment: I literally copied the working onclick JS code into the onload call and it still does not jump to the anchor id.

Comment: I dunno if its me but shoulnd't anchor be named like so : <a name="page0">, <a name="page1">, etc... ?

Comment: I thought name was deprecated on all elements except form inputs.  Anyway, I tried it just in case and still no jumping.